# Why did the Architect tell Neo that Trinity is inside the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

In the 2nd film of Matrix series, *Matrix Reloaded*, at time 2:18:15, the architect told Neo about Trinity:

> Apropos, she entered the Matrix to save your life at the cost of her own.

This makes Neo really upset, as he responds:

> ...No

and chooses another door. What was the intention of the Architect? I feel like it was better for the Architect to let Neo choose the door that brings Neo to the source and the salvation of Zion.

So, what was the Architect intention to somehow make Neo choose another door? He could have hide the truth that Trinity entered to the Matrix and make him choose the first door.

Comment: Choice is part of the balancing of the equation of the Matrix. The Architect always gives the One a choice - as after several failed "beta" Matrixes the Architect and the Oracle co-designed a self balancing system based on choice. What surprises the Architect in this particular iteration is that the One usually makes the choice for the greater good - not love.

Comment: @Withywindle Yes, choice is a part of the equation, but he could hide this truth about Trinity to make him choose for the greater good...

Comment: The choice has to be informed. If the architect railroads him into the "right" decision, there's every chance that Neo will simply refuse further down the road.

Comment: @Valorum I watched that scene more than 30 times. The way that the Architect presented the truth to Neo, made him really emotional about Trinity. I still think he could hide this truth from the sight of Neo... they already lied many times before and this could be just another one ...

Comment: @MichelGokan I believe you are looking at it from a human perspective. Humans lie, the cheat, they misinform. The Architect is a program that balances equations according to rules. Lying or hiding the truth doesn't appear to be within his parameters. "What do you think I am, human?" If I recall the quote correctly.

Comment: @Withywindle based on your answer, and this answer, it seems you are right and he didn't want to misinform him...

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51901/the-matrix-the-architect-cant-lie

Comment: @Withywindle *Matrices

Comment: @SonOfSam yeah, I considered that, but since the Matrix is a proper name I decided proper form would be Matrixes. But since they are all just equations anyway...maybe I'm wrong!

Comment: @Withywindle Saying 'Matrixes' in my head actual hurts. I had to do something.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, very similar...